# Unknown anion (one carbon and two nitrogen atoms, charge 2−)

Tags: nomenclature, ions

What's the name of this ion: $\ce{CN2^2-}$? I think that it has this structure:
$\ce{{}^{-}N=C=N-}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parent molecule is cyanamide.

[image]

The ion is usually referred to as either the cyanamide dianion or the carbimide dianion

[image]

Comment: Since cyanamide also refers to the protonated species, I prefer carbimide (or [carbodiimide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbodiimide), which is the derived functional group), although there may not be an official preference